# Loadrunner and drawbacks using only webservice testing

Tags: web-services, loadrunner

Having a soapui project with a testsuite consisting of multiple web service calls representing a user performing a business process and correlating i.e cookies returned by previous authentication request to the next request and so forth, I want know:
What are the drawbacks, if any, of skipping going through the GUI and only testing on the ws level, given that my chain of ws requests represents exactly what the user would have done through the GUI? None? Easier to maintain the testscript if GUI elements being changed is a benefit. Anyone had some bad experience using this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This argument on validity of just using transport layer requests to the server has been a settled argument for over two decades.   The server does not know or care if a GUI is attached.   Your server is only responding to requests.

Operating against the GUI is only required if you or the tool in use are unable to reproduce the transport layer requests

Comment: You're assuming that the OP only wants to test the server. (Granted that in most cases that is in fact the only requirement).

Answer (score 1):

I think it all depends on what your defined goals are for performance testing the system. If all the GUI pages served by a web server and the resource elements used throughout the GUI (javascript files, css files, images, etc) are elements you want included in the test and response times then you should proceed to include all that. If you're really only concerned with the services layer processing and anything downstream from that (app server, load balancer, database, etc.) then it makes sense to cut out the GUI and hit the services directly.